Can't connect to postgres database running on docker from spring boot
I am currently learning spring boot. From online example it shows setting up postgress database on docker and connecting with spring boot application running locally in my PC.
my docker-compose.yaml has following
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: jobapp
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres_network
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.org
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin_data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres_network
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    name: postgres_data
  pgadmin_data:
    name: pgadmin_data

and application.properties has
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jobapp
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

and pom.xml has
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

I can successfully connect to pgadmin, and it has jobapp database. The containers are running successfully in docker.
when i try following docker command on command line it fail
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U root -d jobapp 

Password for user root:
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"

but this command works fine
docker exec -it postgres_container psql -U root -d jobapp

Also when i try to connect from spring boot i get the error
unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection [FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"] 

Can someone provide some assistance on this  ?

Can anyone provide some help on this?
